# Assigning value to array seat is slow

Tags: c, performance, pointers

I am using temporal difference learning to train computer at playing go. I have noticed that my agent is really slow playing 1 game (like 10 seconds) when it should be able to play 100.000 games in about 20 minutes. After narrowing down the problem I have found out that line no. 5 in the following code is the troublemaker. The code is taken from a much larger function.

```
int i;
 double td = newValue - oldValueWhite;
 for(i = 0; i<FEATURES_SIZE; i++)
 {
     Value[i] =Value[i] + alpha*(td)*((double)phiOldWhite[i]);
 }
```

However, the following code runs smooth as hell:

```
 double tmp:
 int i;
 double td = newValue - oldValueWhite;
 for(i = 0; i<FEATURES_SIZE; i++)
 {
     tmp =Value[i] + alpha*(td)*((double)phiOldWhite[i]);
 }
```

I am not sure if it is the compiler just ignoring the calculations or if the assigning of new value to Value[i] is really slow. Worth mentioning, Value is taken in as pointer to the function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If `tmp` is not used after your `for` loop, your compiler may simply optimize out the  `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using C99, you can try the following (or use gcc extensions `__restrict__`):

```
int i;
double restrict *Value = ...;        // tell compiler Value and phiOldWhite are 
double restrict *phiOldWhite = ...;  // different memory areas

double td = (newValue - oldValueWhite) * td;
for (i = 0; i < FEATURES_SIZE; i++)
{
    Value[i] += td * phiOldWhite[i];
}
```

I used type `double` for phiOldWhite, but you can use your's type.